# Rails Devise - Admin role, model vs attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I know how to create an admin role/user : https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-an-Admin-role

What I am wondering though is if there are any advantages or disadvantages to the two options to consider when deciding between them. Can anyone supply any insight on this please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me muddle the water a bit. I prefer to this via a `Role` table and a join table `UserRole`. This way I can define more than one role without adding another column/table to db.

```
class User
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :roles, :through => :user_roles

  def role?(role)
    role_names.include? role
  end

  def role_names
    @role_names ||= self.roles.map(&:name)
  end

  def role=(role)
    self.roles << Role.find_or_create_by_name(role)
  end
end

class UserRole 
  # integer: user_id, integer: role_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end

class Role
  # string: name
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :users, :through => :user_roles
end
```

Comment: I like this conceptually since it adds a lot of flexibility if that is needed. Conversely of course though is it adds complexity...

Comment: So, in theory, when using this approach incompatible roles can be combined, am I right?

Answer (score 4):

It really depends on what you wish to do with your admin role.  The first option, I would say is a bit secure as the admin role is a unique model in itself.

The second option is straightforward and would help you get going with the least effort.  However, if your users figure out the boolean variable and a way to set it, any user can become an admin and access areas you don't want them to.